# France visa for one day

Tags: visas, schengen, paris, visas-on-arrival

I'm going to London next month and I want to visit Paris for only one day but I don't have time to get a Schengen visa so can I get it from the train station at Paris as I hold a UK visa ?

Comment: It seems extremely unlikely.

Comment: It may depend on what kind of UK visa you hold. If it's a short-term visa, the answer is no, you need to get a Schengen visa.

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: You're wasting your time.  Honestly.  UK visas up to and including ILR are not recognized for visa-on-arrival in Schengen.  ILR will help you apply at a consulate in the UK in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be able to get a visa from the Paris train station as you will be unable to get on the train to Paris without entry clearance to France.

Having said that, some long-term UK visa may allow you to travel to the Schengen area. But according to the wording of the question, these rules are likely not to apply in your case.

You can check the visa requirements using Wikipedia. Type "visa requirements for  citizens wikiedia" in your favorite search engine and follow the links. From the table that you will be getting, go the the "France" row and follow the link to the references. Then click on the reference again. You should now see a "timaticweb" URL in the browser address line. The page that you will be seeing then should list *all* the possible documents/visa types that allow you to enter France.